# Отрисовка содержимого до выполнения кода. JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Пишу игру морской бой, использую JavaFx. Реализовал пока автоматические случайные ходы, но столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня происходит расстановка кораблей, "войнушка" и вычисляется уже победитель!! И только после всего этого отображается графическое окно в котором поражены корабли и видно кто победитель.Почему логика выполняется вначале,а не совместно с Gui. Может проблема в методе initialize(). Что после его завершения проходит отрисовка? Но где тогда писать логику программы? Я хочу поставить небольшую паузу между ходами,чтобы можно было видеть автоматические ходы.

Answer (score 0):

Вы выполняете весь код программы в FX потоке, вот и получается, что он отображает все, что получилось в результате. После запуска игры, все, что не качается изменения графики следует выполнять в отдельном потоке, а результаты хода отправить в FX поток внутри блока Platform.runLater.